# Which values can DocumentClientException.Error.Code have?

Tags: exception, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net

I want my data access layer to handle exceptions thrown by DocumentDB API provided via `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient` class. For example, the optimistic concurrency check implemented using [AccessCondition class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.accesscondition), but others as well.

By looking at the exception thrown, the best way to recognize different `DocumentClient`-specific exceptions seems to be something like this:

```
try { ... }
catch (DocumentClientException exception) 
    when (exception.Error.Code == "Some magic here")
{
    //let the user know how to recover from this..
}
```

I don't like such magic strings as they are not verifiable compile-time. It may contract a typo, or it may change on random moment with DocumentDB client/server changes, etc. Also, it is not clear which such magic codes I could/should be handling since I don't see the `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` .net API containing any `ErrorCodes` enum or constants, nor find any list in documentation.

**Where can I find a list of possible `Error.Code` values DocumentClient API can throw?**

To make it even more confusing, the XmlDoc for `DocumentClient.CreateDocumentAsync` method suggest working instead on http status codes.

**UPDATE:** This question is not about Http status codes but `DocumentClientException.Error.Code` field as I assume the latter is more precise.

Comment: I would accept an answer about Http status code list IF an authoritative quote or convincing reasons are provided stating why `Error.Code` fields should not be used for error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By decompile the version 1.22.0 client, the code is set as a HttpStatusCode enum. I think all the possible values can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx then.

However, what really contains richer information for debug is the Error.Message. Might need to decompile the whole library to figure out, or wait for Microsoft to release the source codes, which is unlikely to happen since the latest update in github was 2 or 3 years ago.

```
public Error Error
{
    get
    {
        if (this.error == null)
        {
            this.error = new Error()
            {
                Code = this.StatusCode.ToString(),
                Message = this.Message
            };
        }
        return this.error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the result I hoped for, but this does explain the lack of documentation -  accepting as answer. Note that the link provided by Howard Edidin seems to provide more information for the context of CosmosDB.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find a list of possible error codes values DocumentClient API can throw?

It's hard to find the completely list of error code that DocumentClinet API throw. The exception is depend on what your request.

> For example, the optimistic concurrency check

Azure Cosmos DB uses **ETags** for handling optimistic concurrency.

When we retrieve a document from Azure Cosmos DB, it always contains an ETag property as apart of our document.

When we then want to send our request to replace a document, we can specify an **AccessCondition with the ETag** we received when we fetched out our document.

If the ETag we send is not current, the server will return a **412 Precondition Failed status code**. In our .NET SDK, this is wrapped up in a **DocumentClientException**.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/dcomartin/DocumentDB.OptimisticConcurrency.Demo/blob/master/src/Demo/OptimtimisticConcurrencyTests.cs) that show the possible problems when the concurrency occurred.

Comment: Yep, I'm asking about the hard part. 
Updated question to emphasize I don't care about specific Etag condition, but a general overview about possible `Error.Code` values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of the [HTTP Status Codes for Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb)

I use the following code in my catch blocks

```
    catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) e.StatusCode,
                    Content = new StringContent(e.Message)
                };
                return resp;
            }
```

Letting the user know how to handle the exception should be done on the client application.

Comment: A good link but it is for REST API, I hope there's something in/for .NET API. Also, note how for example code 400, and 403 the status codes are ambiguous about the underlying reason. I would hope that Error.Code is more detailed.

Comment: Nice to know. Still, but my question is about DocumentClientException.Error.Code, not http status codes.